# Understanding printf in C

Tags: c, linux, printf

I'm trying to understand how `printf` works in C for a simple case. I wrote the following program:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("Test %s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Running `objdump` on the binary I noticed the `Test %s\n` resides in `.rodata`

```
objdump -sj .rodata bin

bin:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .rodata:
 08e0 01000200 54657374 2025730a 00        ....Test %s..
```

So formatted print seems to perform additional pattern copying from `rodata` to somewhere else.

After compiling and running it with `stare ./bin rr` I noticed a `brk` syscall before the actual write. So running it with

```
gdb catch syscall brk
gdb catch syscall write
```

shows that in my case the current break equals to `0x555555756000`, but it then sets to `0x555555777000`. When the `write` occurs the formatted string

```
x/s $rsi
0x555555756260: "Test rr\n"
```

Resides between the "old" and "new" break. After the write occurs the programs exits.

***QUESTION:*** Why do we allocate so many pages and why didn't the break returns to the previous one after write syscall occurs? Is there any reason to use `brk` instead of `mmap` for such formatting?

Comment: You can try exam how much memory is allocated by `brk` before entering `main` function.

Comment: It is normal for a constant string to be in rodata. `So formatted print seems to perform additional pattern copying from rodata to somewhere else.` print has no reason to copy the string, it cannot know the string is a constant or not, why are you saying that ? All initializations etc are done when the program starts

Comment: You can read the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/lk/+/master/lib/libc/printf.c)

Comment: `printf` has it's own buffering. It is usually line buffered.

Comment: @bruno But we cannot modify `rodata` section where the pattern initially resides. So I concluded that to get a formatted string we need to copy the pattern from `rodata` and then replace the `%s` in my case with the actual content.

Comment: @bruno I just added another formatting with different `printf` and noticed that the string pointer remains the same for both of the strings. It seems we copy the pattern once and then replace the placeholder whenever formatting occurs.

Comment: Re "formatted print seems to perform additional pattern copying from rodata to somewhere else": Yes, to the standard output ;-).

Comment: @Ôrel Astonished to see macros in the source... do the developers not trust the inlining capabilities of their compilers?

Comment: @Ôrel Besides, the interesting (regarding the question) part appears to be in the `_dvprintf()` call which is probably the platform specific part.

Comment: @St.Antario: the format string is never mutated. `printf` copies byte by byte into the destination until it reaches the first `%` char, then it formats the next argument using whatever formatting specifier is there and continues. Changing strings in place by inserting data is pretty much impossible in any language, in general.

Comment: Please remember that you're seeing the behavior of a specific implementation of `printf` for a specific platform.  There's nothing in the C language standard that mandates *any* of what you're seeing at the system level.

Comment: @Groo So it means we are copying the pattern any time we are formatting it from ro to some preallocated heap buffer?

Comment: @St.Antario: just to clarify, when you say "copying the pattern", it might imply that the string is really *copied* and then changed afterwards. But what any implementation of this function will have to do is: 1) read from the const pattern string **one character at a time** and 2) write this character or some formatted value *somewhere else*. Whether this *somewhere else* is directly to the output, or to an intermediate malloc'ed buffer, depends on the implementation. There are [many "tiny printf"](https://github.com/mpaland/printf) implementations which don't allocate any temporary buffers.

Comment: In your example, the function presumably allocates a temp. buffer, which will later be flushed to stdout. It then reads the first 5 characters from `"Test %s\n"` and writes them to this buffer. Then it encounters `'%'`, which is a special character. It "swallows" it (doesn't write it to the temp buffer) and checks the next character. It reads the next char as the formatting specifier `'s'`, swallows it, and then probably calls a different function which copies the contents of the nul-terminated string `argv[1]` into the buffer. When everything is done, it flushes the buffer to stdout.

Comment: @Groo makes sense to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`brk()` (and it's companion `sbrk()`) is some kind of `mmap()` specialized to manipulate the heap size. It is there for historical reasons, the libc could also use `mmap()` or `mremap()` directly.

The heap is expanded as additional memory is allocated, for example with `malloc()`, which happens internally in the libc, for example to have enough space to create the actual string from the format string and the parameters or many other internal things (i.e. the output buffers when using buffered io with the f* function family).

If some parts of the heap are not used anymore, it is often not automatically deallocated for two main reasons: the heap may be fragmented, and/or the unused heap does not fall below a certain threshold which justifies the operation, because it might be needed again soon.

As a side note: the format string itself is certainly not copied from the ro-section to the heap, this would be completely useless. But the result string is (usually) built on the heap.

Comment: `the format string itself is certainly not copied from the ro-section to the heap` Would not modifying `ro`-section cause segmentation fault? I just tried and it does.

Comment: This is the code causing `segv`:  `char *p = "Test %s\n"; printf(p, argv[1]); printf(p, argv[2]); p[5] = 'r'; p[6] = 'r';` for `./bin rr tt`. Even if modifying string-literal is UB in C, but we can write a hand-written assembly and modifying `.rodata` causes segfault anyway.

Comment: @StAntario You misunderstood me, the _result string_ is _built_ on the heap, but the the _format string_ is not copied to the heap prior to that. This is a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we allocate so many pages ?

Using a system call is costly, so the library ask for more than you would like at this moment because it is highly probable that you will want more very soon. Managing memory in user mode is less costly. It is a matter of granularity.

> and why didn't the break returns to
>   the previous one after write syscall occurs?

Again, why free if the probability that you will ask for more soon is high?

> Is there any reason to use `brk` instead of `mmap` for such formatting?

It is a matter of choice, this depends on implementation.

Aside: Your question is more about "memory allocation policy" than "understanding printf" (that is the context of).